# If cell accessory type is set to "checkmark" does that make it automatically selected?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I have a table that stores index values in an array.

On select of a row they append to the array

The issues comes when I click the previous button and want to populate the table with those indexes and automatically check mark them if they're in the array.

Although my question is: Will I need to run a loop on `cellForRowAt` and check if they're in an array and assign the checkmark. (Will that count as 'selected' or will I need to loop though and call `tableview.selectRow` and then assign checkmark?

I have this so far but am running into issues.

```
  func cellForRowAt: 

       if let question = allQuestions[currentQuestion - 1].userAnswer {
                if question.contains([indexPath.row]) {
                   // print("contains row")
                    //tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
                    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                } else {
                   // print("does not contain")
                    cell.selectionStyle = .none
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
```

is not the same thing as

```
tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
```

Calling `tableView.selectRow` will set the `isSelected` property on the cell when it's displayed. Your cell subclass can then use that property to set the `accessoryType` rather then doing it in `cellForRow`.

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        accessoryType = isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    }
}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`, tell the `UiTableView` which of the rows should be selected.